# Error: The following params are required: Client ID, Client Secret on clarifai api on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

- List item

  import React, { Component } from 'react';

  ```html
      <script 
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

      import React, { Component } from 'react';
      import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
      import Clarifai from 'clarifai';
      import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
      import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
      import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';
      import './App.css';


      const app = new Clarifai.App({
        apikey:'9608eb25e72a49ed86f4cc940e77eed2'
        });
      const particlesOptions = {
                          polygon:{
                            number:{
                              value:30,
                              density:{
                                enable:true,
                                value_area:1000
                              }
                            } 
                          }
                      }

      class App extends Component {
        constructor() {
          super();
          this.state = {
            input:'',
          }
        }
        onInputChange = (event) => {
          console.log(event.target.value);
        }
        onButtonSubmit =() => {
          console.log('click');
          app.models.predict("a403429f2ddf4b49b307e318f00e528b", "https://samples.clarifai.com/face-det.jpg").then(
          function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          },
          function(err) {
            // there was an error
          }
        );
        }


        render() {
          return (
            <div className="App">
              <Particles className ='particles' params={particlesOptions} />


              <Navigation/>
              <ImageLinkForm onInputChange={this.onInputChange} 
                onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}/>
              <Rank/>
              {
              
            /*<Logo/>
              
              <FaceRecognition/>*/}
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      export default App;
  ```

  ```html
      <pre> import React, { Component } from 'react';
      import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
      import Clarifai from 'clarifai';
      import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
      import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
      import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';
      import './App.css';


      const app = new Clarifai.App({
        apikey:'9608eb25e72a49ed86f4cc940e77eed2'
        });
      const particlesOptions = {
                          polygon:{
                            number:{
                              value:30,
                              density:{
                                enable:true,
                                value_area:1000
                              }
                            } 
                          }
                      }

      class App extends Component {
        constructor() {
          super();
          this.state = {
            input:'',
          }
        }
        onInputChange = (event) => {
          console.log(event.target.value);
        }
        onButtonSubmit =() => {
          console.log('click');
          app.models.predict("a403429f2ddf4b49b307e318f00e528b", "https://samples.clarifai.com/face-det.jpg").then(
          function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          },
          function(err) {
            // there was an error
          }
        );
        }


        render() {
          return (
            <div className="App">
              <Particles className ='particles' params={particlesOptions} />


              <Navigation/>
              <ImageLinkForm onInputChange={this.onInputChange} 
                onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}/>
              <Rank/>
              {
              
            /*<Logo/>
              
              <FaceRecognition/>*/}
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      export default App;
  ```

  ```html
      import React, { Component } from 'react';
      import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
      import Clarifai from 'clarifai';
      import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
      import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
      import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';
      import './App.css';


      const app = new Clarifai.App({
        apikey:'9608eb25e72a49ed86f4cc940e77eed2'
        });
      const particlesOptions = {
                          polygon:{
                            number:{
                              value:30,
                              density:{
                                enable:true,
                                value_area:1000
                              }
                            } 
                          }
                      }

      class App extends Component {
        constructor() {
          super();
          this.state = {
            input:'',
          }
        }
        onInputChange = (event) => {
          console.log(event.target.value);
        }
        onButtonSubmit =() => {
          console.log('click');
          app.models.predict("a403429f2ddf4b49b307e318f00e528b", "https://samples.clarifai.com/face-det.jpg").then(
          function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          },
          function(err) {
            // there was an error
          }
        );
        }


        render() {
          return (
            <div className="App">
              <Particles className ='particles' params={particlesOptions} />


              <Navigation/>
              <ImageLinkForm onInputChange={this.onInputChange} 
                onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}/>
              <Rank/>
              {
              
            /*<Logo/>
              
              <FaceRecognition/>*/}
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      export default App;
  ```

  import Particles from 'react-particles-js';

  import Clarifai from 'clarifai';

  import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';

  import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';

  import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';

  import './App.css';

  const app = new Clarifai.App({
    apikey:'9608eb25e72a49ed86f4cc940e77eed2'
    });
  const particlesOptions = {
                      polygon:{
                        number:{
                          value:30,
                          density:{
                            enable:true,
                            value_area:1000
                          }
                        } 
                      }
                  }

  class App extends Component {

  constructor() {

  ```
  super();

  this.state = {
    input:'',
  }
  ```

  }

  onInputChange = (event)=>{
      console.log(event.target.value);

  }

  onButtonSubmit =() => {
      console.log('click');
      app.models.predict("a403429f2ddf4b49b307e318f00e528b","https://samples.clarifai.com/face-det.jpg").then(
      function(response) {

  ```
    console.log(response);

  },

  function(err) {

  }
  ```

  );
    }

  render() {

  ```
  return (

    <div className="App">

      <Particles className ='particles' params={particlesOptions} />


      <Navigation/>

      <ImageLinkForm onInputChange={this.onInputChange} 

        onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}/>

      <Rank/>

      {

    /*<Logo/>

      <FaceRecognition/>*/}

    </div>
  );
  ```

  }
  }
  export default App;

  Help me !! What to do ?

Comment: Please detail your question in the post and better format your code. If there's a lot of code required to reproduce the issue, consider a demo, for example, over at https://codesandbox.io

Comment: thanks.Here it is.https://codesandbox.io/s/8837rmypk9         I'm trying to use Clarifai face recognition api in my react web app.But I'm getting "Error: The following params are required: Client ID, Client Secret"error.I have npm Clarifai install.

Comment: What version of clarifai are you using?  You might have to update

Comment: Its showing npm clarifai version is 2.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to [Clarifai docs](https://clarifai.com/developer/guide/authentication#authorize-api-calls), change the following line:

```
const app = new Clarifai.App({
  apikey: "9608eb25e72a49ed86f4cc940e77eed2"
});
```

to

```
const app = new Clarifai.App({
  apiKey: "9608eb25e72a49ed86f4cc940e77eed2"
});
```

It's `apiKey` and not `apikey`, changing this removed the error in a sandbox.